# how to remove "sticky position" div background?

Tags: html, css, svg, sticky

I put one SVG end of the body. the SVG position is sticky, but make a white space end of the page.

[image: end of page is white space]

html

```
  <div class="chat-icon-div d-flex flex-row justify-content-end">
    <svg class="chat-icon-svg" id="" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="70" height="70" viewBox="0, 0, 400,400">
        <g id="">
            <path id="path0"
                ...... "
                stroke="none" fill="#f9f4f6" fill-rule=""></path>


            <path id="path1"
                d="....."
                stroke="none" fill="#ab043b" fill-rule=""></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.chat-icon-div {
position: sticky;
bottom: 170px;
```

padding-left: 30px;
background: none;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.chat-icon-div {
position: fixed;
bottom: 50px;
left: 15px;}
```

You should try this.